# React Native bottom navigation hide

Tags: react-native

Currently I am **new to React Native** and I have created a project. so I want to ask you How to ***show bottom tap navigation*** in just one *specific screen*?

**For example** I want to show it on **Homescreen**.

```
const APP_TAB = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Job:Home_STACK,
    Chat:ChatScreen,
    NewFeed:NewFeed,
    CV:cvScreen,
    Profile:ProfileScreen,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned below you can use this logic

```
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
        let tabBarVisible = true;
        if (navigation.state.routes.length > 1) {
          tabBarVisible = false;
        }
        return {
          tabBarVisible,
        };
      },
```

in your every stackNavigater

```
const HomeNavigation = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
          return {
            headerTitle: (
              <Header
                navigate={navigation.navigate}
              />
            ),
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#d63921',
            },
            headerRight: (
              <HeaderRight
                navigate={navigation.navigate}
              />
            ),
          };
        },
      },
    },
    **{
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
        let tabBarVisible = true;
        if (navigation.state.routes.length > 1) {
          tabBarVisible = false;
        }
        return {
          tabBarVisible,
        };
      },**
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
      mode: 'card',
      lazy: false,
    },
  );


const ProfileNavigation = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Profile: {
        screen: ProfileScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
          return {
            headerTitle: (
            )}

    },
    **{
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
        let tabBarVisible = true;
        if (navigation.state.routes.length > 1) {
          tabBarVisible = false;
        }
        return {
          tabBarVisible,
        };
      },***
      initialRouteName: 'Profile',
      mode: 'card',
      lazy: false,
    },
  );
```

Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Let me try and I will tell you later

Answer (score 0):

In React Navigation 6x,
You can hide it from any screen you want with                   tabBarStyle: { display: "none" }.

Below is the example:

```
<Tab.Screen
            name="Cart"
            component={Cart}
            options={{
                header: () => null,
                tabBarShowLabel: false,
                tabBarStyle: { display: "none" },
            }}
        />
```